# Azure PowerBI dataset refresh via API doesn't refresh its reports

Tags: powerbi

When I do a manual dataset refresh via the powerbi app the report that is based on that dataset is automatically updated. I was hoping the same behaviour when I refresh dataset with the API, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset-in-group

After successfully processing the request I get a positive response like this, but the report that is based on that dataset remains unchanged:
[image: status from api]

On the other hand, the refresh done inside the powerbi refreshes the report but also has this additional QUERY type:
[image: status from powerbi]

Can anyone explain me why this is happening and what is the best way to get that report updated automatically.

Comment: Have you configured the dataset credentials properly in PowerBI service?  in the second screenshot there is an error visible.